# Bare Expo app unable to build when created first time (Expo SDK 42)

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, gradle, expo

I created a react native app using

```
expo init AwesomeProject
```

I chose **bare workflow**.

As soon as I try to run the app using `yarn android`, the build crashes.

This is the error:

```
 > Task :unimodules-react-native-adapter:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.8/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
284 actionable tasks: 284 executed
C:\Users\prana\Desktop\new-app\new-app\SphereV2\node_modules\expo-modules-autolinking\build\index.js:14
        .option('-i, --ignore-paths <ignorePaths...>', 'Paths to ignore when looking up for modules.', (value, previous) => (previous ?? []).concat(value))
                                                                                                                                       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1053:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at [eval]:1:1
    at Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:120:18)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:309:38)
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: C:\Users\prana\Desktop\new-app\new-app\SphereV2\node_modules\expo-application\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\application\ApplicationModule.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\Users\prana\Desktop\new-app\new-app\SphereV2\node_modules\expo-updates\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\updates\UpdatesConfiguration.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: C:\Users\prana\Desktop\new-app\new-app\SphereV2\node_modules\expo-constants\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\constants\ConstantsService.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\Users\prana\Desktop\new-app\new-app\SphereV2\node_modules\expo-file-system\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\filesystem\FileSystemModule.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\Users\prana\Desktop\new-app\new-app\SphereV2\node_modules\expo-file-system\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\filesystem\FileSystemModule.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
C:\Users\prana\Desktop\new-app\new-app\SphereV2\node_modules\@unimodules\react-native-adapter\android\src\main\java\org\unimodules\adapters\react\ModuleRegistryAdapter.java:26: error: cannot find symbol
    mModuleRegistryProvider = new ReactModuleRegistryProvider(new ExpoModulesPackageList().getPackageList(), null);
                                                                  ^
  symbol:   class ExpoModulesPackageList
  location: class ModuleRegistryAdapter
1 error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':unimodules-react-native-adapter:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5m 40s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
C:\Users\prana\Desktop\new-app\new-app\SphereV2\node_modules\expo-modules-autolinking\build\index.js:14
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

enter code here
```

This is my environment after running `react-native info`:

```
System:
    OS: Windows 10 10.0.19043
    CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-10210U CPU @ 1.60GHz
    Memory: 682.79 MB / 7.79 GB
  Binaries:
    Node: 12.18.3 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
    Yarn: 1.22.10 - ~\AppData\Roaming\npm\yarn.CMD
    npm: 6.14.6 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
    Watchman: Not Found
  SDKs:
    Android SDK: Not Found
    Windows SDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: Version  4.1.0.0 AI-201.8743.12.41.6953283
    Visual Studio: Not Found
  Languages:
    Java: 11.0.2
    Python: 3.8.4
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: 16.13.1 => 16.13.1
    react-native: ~0.63.4 => 0.63.4
    react-native-windows: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found
```

/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properites:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.8-all.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

/android/build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 30
        targetSdkVersion = 30
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0")

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

The current **Gradle version on my system is Gradle 6.8**.
I have tried using Gradle 7.0 as well, and in that case, I end up getting an error saying:

```
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?? I am running the latest expo SDK version 42.

Comment: Also, till SDK 41 everything was working as expected, Right?

Comment: I've created a post on [Expo Forums](https://forums.expo.io/t/build-failed-on-bare-workflow-sdk-42/54191/3) regarding this issue. You can also reply there by adding your environments etc. This would help.

Comment: @Kartikey do you know how to go back to SDK 41?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

expo-modules-autolinking is built for esnext. This is why `??` operator is unrecognized in the index.js file.

You can update to node v16

Or recompiled it for es5 by changing target in tsconfig.json of the expo-modules-autolinking module. Then by doing `cd node_modules/expo-modules-autolinking`, I recompiled it with `npx tsc` command

Comment: Updated to Node v14 and it worked thank you!

Answer (score 1):

this was a bug when running on windows. uninstall react-native-unimodules and reinstall it to get the latest version of @unimodules/react-native-adapter  (6.3.3)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue after install `expo-location` plugin, in my case installing `expo-modules-autolinking` the error go away, maybe you wanna try it

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup Node v16
In linux, Android studio uses the Node under `/usr/local/bin/node`.

If you still get this issue even though **node --version** returns `v16.14.0`, you need to update the symbolic link

```
sudo ln -s $(which node) /usr/local/bin/node
```